# Interpolation of Sobolev/Besov spaces in the limiting case q = ∞

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, interpolation-spaces, besov-spaces

I'm interested in the interpolation space ($1\le p_0,p_1\le\infty$, $0<\theta<1$)

$$
 X=(L_{p_0}(0;1),W^1_{p_1}(0,1))_{\theta,q}\quad\text{with}\quad q=\infty\ \ \text{and}\ \ p_0\ne p_1 .
$$

It seems to me that $X\subset B_{p_\theta-\varepsilon,q}^{\theta-\varepsilon}(0;1)$ (or $X\subset H^{\theta-\varepsilon}_{p_\theta-\varepsilon}(0;1)$) for any $\varepsilon>0$, but I do not know how to prove this (here $\frac{1}{p_\theta}=\frac{1-\theta}{p_0}+\frac{\theta}{p_1}$).

I was barely able to find considerations of the limiting case $q=\infty$ for $p_0\ne p_1$ in the literature. In Triebel (thm 2.4.1/5) the case $q=\infty$ is skipped. In Berg, Lyofstryom there is thm 6.4.5/3, which contains the case $q=\infty$ with the diagonal restriction $p_\theta=q$. I'm able to slightly modify the proof for the case $p_\theta\ne q$:
$$(L_{p_0}(0;1),L_{p_1}(0;1))_{\theta,q}=L_{p_\theta,q}(0;1)\subset L_{p_\theta-\varepsilon}(0;1).$$
But in Berg, Lyofstryom something strange is written: the proof of 6.4.5/3 (which includes the case $q=\infty$) follows from 5.6.2, which does not include the case $q=\infty$. This is confusing to me.

I was able to find the case $q=\infty$ in the old Peetre preprint "New Thoughts on Besov spaces" (ch.5, theorems 2, 4, and 6, which describes X in terms of Lorenz spaces), but I'm not sure if I can trust this work in thin cases (since the base thm 2 is given without proof).

There is an obvious way to use Sobolev type embedding like $W^1_{p_1}(0;1)\subset B^s_{p_0,q}(0;1)$ if $p_0>p_1$ or $W^1_{p_1}(0;1)\subset W^1_{p_0}(0;1)$ if $p_0<p_1$, but in both cases the resulting interpolation space is worse than $B_{p_\theta-\varepsilon,\infty}^{\theta-\varepsilon}(0;1)$

I'm interested if there is a way to find an embedding $X\subset B^s_{p,q}(0;1)$ (or $X\subset H^s_p(0;1)$) such that $s$ and $p$ are close to $\theta$ and $p_\theta$.

Comment: Please see Chapter 5 in the book "Interpolation of Operators" by Bennett and Sharpley.

Comment: Onur Oktay, thank you! Unfortunately, only the simple classical case $p_0=p_1$ is considered this book.

Comment: It seems to me that now I know how to solve it. Unfortunately, the my translation of the Triebel book contains a typo! So the only thing needed is inclusion $(L_{p_0}(0;1),W^1_{p_1}(0;1))_{\theta,\infty}\subset(L_{p_0}(0;1),W^1_{p_1}(0;1))_{\theta-\varepsilon,q}$ that holds for any $0<\varepsilon<\theta$ and $1\le q\le\infty$ (since $W^1_{p_1}(0;1)\subset L_{p_0}(0;1)$). It remains to set $q=p_\theta$ and obtain the diagonal case.